# Why my sql query not work in PHP Script

Tags: php, html, mysql

i try to query

```html
<?php 

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `takelist` LEFT JOIN repair_list ON takelist.repair_id=repair_list.repair_id WHERE repair_list.status='รอซ่อมแซม' && repair_list.responsible='$name'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
?>
```

and echo number of row in my phpmyadmin i see 1 row 
and then i query and echo rows it show 0

Comment: `$rows = mysql_error();`

Comment: `WHERE repair_list.status='รอซ่อมแซม'` what this value `'รอซ่อมแซม'`

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code I can only suggest checking to see if $connection is valid, the query looks correct. mysql_connect may not be connecting to the DB as you wanted. Check your credentials. @VadivelS the status is written in Thai ( I think ). This should be fine.

Comment: then i can query that code
but after i use mysql_num_rows

Comment: it say Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: May want to try changing your charset

Comment: And changing to `mysqli` functions

Comment: @NonBrazilian That error means that the SQL query is failing, so the assignment to `$sql` is `false`, rather than a Resource Identifier. What is your DB schema? Also, please update to `mysqli_*` functions (at a minimum) and check for SQL injection.